Replacing RelatedLink in old TeamFoundation client to new rest based WebApi Models
I am trying to find a way to make this code segment work again, but i cant find a good replacement for getting the links matching specific work item. It is supposed to find the related work items (this is a segment of it)
for (int i = 0; i < it.Links.Count; i++)
{
    if (it.Links.[i].BaseType == BaseLinkType.RelatedLink)
    {
        RelatedLink ln = (RelatedLink)it.Links[i];
        if (!ln.LinkTypeEnd.ImmutableName.Contains("Hierarchy") && ln.LinkTypeEnd.Name == "Related")
        {
            if (ln.RelatedWorkItemId == id)
            {
                try
                {
                    WorkItem susp = wis.GetWorkItem(id);
                    if ((string)it.Fields["System.TeamProject"] == (string)susp.Fields["System.TeamProject"])
                        root = susp;
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}

i tried using this:
var result = awaithttpClient.GetReportingLinksByLinkTypeAsync(project).ConfigureAwait(false);
but it only gets links by project and i cant seem to find a way to apply it.

Hi @LinusFlemström, Have you got a chance to check my answer below to use REST API? Thx.

I can use this REST API to get the work items with the LinkType of Related in my project. Here is a c# sample for your reference.
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting;

namespace GetWIT
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string org = "OrgName";
            string project = "ProjectName";
            string personalAccessToken = "xxxxxx";
            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalAccessToken)));

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}");

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);

                var linkType = "System.LinkTypes.Related";
                var startDateTime = "2024-04-30T07:00:00.00Z";

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"_apis/wit/reporting/workitemlinks?linkTypes={linkType}&startDateTime={startDateTime}&api-version=7.1-preview.3").Result;

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented));

            }
        }
    }
}


